# Me puede ayudar, no se ejecuta sentencia mysql en funcion php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Amigos tengo una funcion php, donte tengo una sentencia de mysql para insercion de datos, pero no se ejecuta quizas me podrian ayudar a encontrar el error

```
function RegistrarServicioEP($nombreser,$descripcionser,$fotoser)
{

    //echo $fotoser;

    $mensaje= "";
    $idempresa= BuscarUltimaEmpresa();
    $elservicios = 1;

    echo $nombreser;
    echo $descripcionser;
    echo $idempresa;
    echo $elservicios;

    if(isset($nombreser, $descripcionser, $fotoserm, $idempresa, $elservicios))
    {

    $queryS = "INSERT INTO servicios(idempresa, nombre, descripcion, imagen, sereliminadologico) VALUES (".$idempresa.",'".$nombreser."','".$descripcionser."','".$fotoser."','".$elservicios."')";

    $conS = conexionBD();
    $accionS = mysqli_query($conS,$queryS);
    //PersonasEP($eppersona, $epcargo, $epmensaje, $epfoto, $idempresa);

    if($accionS)
    {
        $mensaje = "Correcto";
    }else{
        $mensaje = "No se pudo guardar Servicio";
    }
    }else {
        $mensaje = "No llegan todos los valores";
    }

    return $mensaje;
    echo $mensaje;
}
```

He colocado unos echos para constatar que si entraba a la funcion y llegan los datos

Comment: Algún mensaje de error?

Comment: No, es mas no me refleja ni los mensajes q que le coloque, solo muestra los datos que ingrese con el echo que le coloque pero de ahi no me muestra ni ejecuta nada

Comment: En tu **if(isset( ... ))** tienes una variable **$fotoserm**, esta variable no debería ser **$fotoser** ?

Comment: Ni siquiera deberías usar `isset`, sino verificar el estado de las variables antes de pasarlas a la función actual. Para un futuro, ten en cuenta también que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Necesitarás implementar consultas preparadas para blindar el código contra este tipo de ataques.